# ACCESS SQL Query to exclude 2 variables using the "NOT IN" clause

Tags: sql-server, combobox

I am populating in ADO - ACCESS 2 sets of 2 Comboboxes (total 4 comboboxes: 2 for the rate plans and 2 for the associated room types). 
When a user selects a rate plan and the associated room type in the 1st set of comboboxes, the 2nd set of comboboxes excludes the room type selected before if the rate plan selected in the 2nd set of comboboxes is the same as the one selected in the 1st set. 
I need to give users the ability, however, to select a 3rd combination of rate plan / room type but, as per previous functionality, I would like that if in the 3rd set of rate plans, the user selects the very same rates plans as the ones selected in the 1st and 2nd sets of comboboxes, the associated roomtype is retrieved without showing the rooms selected in the 1st and 2nd set of comboboxes. 
To this aim I am using the following SQL query in my recordset:

```
SELECT Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId,
       RoomTypes.RoomType,
       RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy
    FROM RoomTypes
    RIGHT JOIN Hotel_Rates_Room ON
        RoomTypes.RoomTypeId = Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId
    WHERE Hotel_Rates_Room.HotelId='00000036-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
      AND Hotel_Rates_Room.RateTypeId='C6457A97-D5A5-4F34-A6E5-3256578B6562'
      OR Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId NOT IN (
        SELECT RoomTypeId FROM Hotel_Rates_Room
        WHERE RoomTypeId='B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF'
          AND RoomTypeId='FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0')
      AND Active=0
    GROUP BY  Hotel_Rates_Room.HotelId,
              Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId,
              RoomTypes.RoomType,
              RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy ORDER BY RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy
```

The part that is not working and that I want to underscore is the following one:

```
...NOT IN (
    SELECT RoomTypeId FROM Hotel_Rates_Room
    WHERE RoomTypeId='B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF'
      AND RoomTypeId='FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0')...
```

What I am trying to do here is to select all room types associated to the rate type selected where the roomtype ID is not B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF and FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0.

This query is not excluding the 2 room types but it's showing them all. What's wrong with this query in your opinion? Would you suggest me other approaches?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you format your query? It's not easy to read all on one line

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
NOT IN('B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF', 'FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0')
```

The problem you have is most likely because of the `AND`. A `RoomTypeId` can't be both `'B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF'` and `'FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0'`, the effect is that the `not in` query returns an empty resultset, and so all records are returned. You probably meant to use `OR`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right 100%. The final and working solution is NOT IN(SELECT RoomTypeId FROM Hotel_Rates_Room WHERE RoomTypeId='B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF' OR  RoomTypeId='FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0')

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept this answer for future visitors.

Comment: Still cannot accept due to the fact that  I have too few points.

Comment: You can always accept an answer to your own question, you may not be able to vote up. To accept click the check-mark on the left-side of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you rewrite it this way

```
 SELECT Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId, RoomTypes.RoomType, RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy   
    FROM RoomTypes  RIGHT JOIN Hotel_Rates_Room 
    ON RoomTypes.RoomTypeId = Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId 
    WHERE
    Hotel_Rates_Room.HotelId='00000036-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'  
    AND Hotel_Rates_Room.RateTypeId='C6457A97-D5A5-4F34-A6E5-3256578B6562' 
    AND Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId NOT IN ('B1C02BD5-80B7-4A65-9699-142D07AB70CF','FF3756C7-4D75-4579-A48B-C8A911D584A0')
    AND Active=0  
    GROUP BY  Hotel_Rates_Room.HotelId,Hotel_Rates_Room.RoomTypeId, RoomTypes.RoomType,RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy 
ORDER BY RoomTypes.MaxOccupancy
```

Comment: Thank you Bodgan but this solution returns all roomtypes as per my initial query. Cannot understand why. Thanks